# Can anyone help me with I/O redirection of C/C++ Program to a File without using filestreams on Repl.it

Tags: c, bash, replit

I'm trying to do I/O redirection in the open shell on repl.it. Taking the input from one file to run through the program. Outputting to a new file but nothing shows up? I'm only used to doing it from Windows using the CMD.

Shell:

```
~/maybe-lab6and7$ clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c < address.txt > 
open.txt
~/maybe-lab6and7$
```

Comment: IF your `main.c` is really a compiled program AND you have changed the permissions for execute access with `chmod +x main.c`, then your current working directory is not included in your PATH variable, either specify a "full-path" to the program, i.e. `/full/path/to/main.c` or a relative path like `./main.c ...` Did you just type in your exercise code as `main.c` and then try running your scripts above? If yes, you need to complie it first maybe like `cc main.c -o myFirstProg`. Good luck.

Comment: You've destroyed whatever was in `address.txt` by using `> address.txt`.  You're trying to read from a non-existent file.  It's as if you have the meanings of `>` and `<` reversed in your thinking. 
 You have to compile your program before it will run; you can't run `main.c` if it contains C source code.

Comment: It's not reversed in Windows command prompt...

Comment: @HippiiDippii : I don't know `clang-7`, but from the context, I would assume that it is a C compiler. I find it strange that you try to feed something into the stdin, and probably it is simply ignoring it. If `open.txt` is empty afterwards, it means that the compiler did not write anything to stdout either. Did you check stderr? Did you check the exit code? Has `main` be generated?

Comment: strongly suggest posting your source code so we can see what your trying to do.

Comment: Main has been generated and this is what it shows clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
 ./main. In visual studios, after building the program, I would run the file through the .exe but with repl.it I'm confused on how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After compiling and linking your program, if no compile problems and no link problems occur, you will have an executable in the current directory.  (Lets say the executable is named: `main`.)

Then, after changing the program permissions so `main` is executable,
you can execute the program similar to:

```
./main  < sourcedata.txt  > destinationdata.txt
```

The result is that `main` can read the `sourcedata.txt` file from `stdin` and the output from the program (instead of being displayed on the terminal) will be written to `destinationdata.txt`.

Comment: @Yunnosch,  always a possibility, However that is not the question the OP ask

Comment: I'm using repl.it any advice on that would be nice. I'm aware that you have to use an executable file as I've done it before with visual studios/ windows. But repl.it is slightly different.

Comment: Please explain how repl.it changes things. This answer seems to match the question you asked. If there is a relevant other problem, on top of the mistakes you made in the way of  using main.c, you might have to create a separate new question on that problem. Because here you would risk a "moving target question" with too much editing.

Comment: @Yuunosch this is the result that I get in shell on repl.it: ~/maybe-lab6and7$ main < address.txt > open.txt
bash: main: command not found

Comment: If `repl,it` is linux based, then after compiling + linking, the resulting program can be executed via `./main`  OR you can use `chmod +x main` to make it executable, then you will not need the `./` infront of `main`

Comment: The executable should already be marked executable by the compiler? The executable permission isn't related to needing `./`, it's always required unless the executable is on the path

Comment: in C, on linux, the output from the compiler+linker does not contain the `execute` permission.  It can be executed via `./nameOfExecutable`  Much more useful to change the permissions to include the `executable permission, then it can be executed via: `nameOfExecutable`

Comment: @user3629249 have you tried this on Linux? having to use `./` is nothing to do with the executable permission, if a program isn't marked executable you won't be able to execute it at all

Comment: Actually, @AlanBirtles,  it does not have to have the `x` permission to be executed,  (assuming the file is otherwise able to be executed.) the leading `./` enables execution of the file, even though it does not have the `x` permission

Comment: not on any Linux installation I've ever used: https://imgur.com/QWlAWeh